# Search Any Folder or File in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search

I want to search user created file or Folder in windows7.. I have downloaded `GOOGLE DESKTOP` to search my files.. but it only searches Installed files included in ProgramFiles and Control Panel.. but i want to search user created files that places in any drive in MyComputer, i dont want to use search option provided by Windows 7.

Is there any Software like `Google Desktop` to search user created files and folder?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look [here](http://www.guidingtech.com/7460/alternative-file-search-engines-windows/) for three alternative search engines

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some answers to similar superuser questions:

[Best way to *confidently* search files and contents in Windows without using an indexing service?](https://superuser.com/questions/26593/best-way-to-confidently-search-files-and-contents-in-windows-without-using-an)

https://superuser.com/questions/135423/whats-a-good-alternative-to-windows-search-for-files-and-folders

[Best Windows software to search file content](https://superuser.com/questions/66699/best-windows-software-to-search-file-content)