# Is there a tool on Windows that offers what Spotlight offers on OS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, desktop-search

Is there a tool on Windows 7 that offers what Spotlight offers on OS X? I mean a deep-fast search on everything that stands on local disks. I also mean : search on the content of those files. So the ability to find the files that contain a specified word or sentence.

Comment: Please explain: What features are you missing from Windows' search function?

Comment: See also: [Best Windows software to search file content](http://superuser.com/questions/66699/best-windows-software-to-search-file-content), [Best way to *confidently* search files and contents in Windows without using an indexing service?](http://superuser.com/questions/26593/best-way-to-confidently-search-files-and-contents-in-windows-without-using-an)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of [Desktop Search Engines on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines#Desktop_search_engines). I am sure you'll find something in the list that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I use "Everything" from voidtools it is very fast and uses very little resources. It finds things on any of your NTFS partitions. It can use regular expressions or just standard wildcards.

http://www.voidtools.com/

Comment: Everything is different from Spotlight because Spotlight searches inside files, which Everything does not.