# Howto search in PDFs using regular expressions?

Tags: pdf, search, regex

Usually I use Notepad++ to search in file(s) using regular expressions. Today I am wondering if there is a PDF program that does the same for PDFs. Of course I could convert the PDF to text and use Notepad++ but is there a more easy way without converting?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows Developer Preview and Windows 7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

several options:

- [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) (top answer in [Best way to *confidently* search files and contents in Windows without using an indexing service?](https://superuser.com/questions/26593/) )
- [DnGrep](http://code.google.com/p/dngrep/) which is a Free and Open source software. Unfortunately it is at the moment only available on Windows. (a feature request has been opened for other platforms [here](https://github.com/dnGrep/dnGrep/issues/310))

Comment: @akira What about in Linux?

Answer (score 4):

1. Agent Ransack is free (lite) and supports PDF as its release notes confirm.
2. PowerGREP is a commercial product.

Just as you said, the evident alternative is to convert PDFs to text. One way for a programmer to set that up for bulk processing is by using the Python package PDFMiner. Agent Ransack uses "pdftotext" from the Xpdf project (and you can too).

Comment: sidenote: Agent Ransack is the lite version of FileLocator

Comment: Thanks! I looked more closely. The vendor's release notes confirm that File Locator Lite aka Agent Ransack does support PDF. Editing my answer.

Comment: Agent Ransack does the job. You might also want to try DnGrep.