# Is it possible search mutliple phrases in PDF at the same time?

Tags: pdf, search

Is it possible search mutliple phrases in PDF at one time?  For instance let's say that I have few literals to look for inside pdf: `0123, BOOM, TAG, LOREM, IPSUM`.

Is it possible to find them in one search?

Comment: Check out AgentRansack mentioned here: http://superuser.com/questions/400930/howto-search-in-pdfs-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the question if you're looking for a document with ALL the terms or a document with ANY of the terms but either way a tool like [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) would do the trick:

To search for ANY of the terms you'd search for:

```
0123 OR BOOM OR TAG OR LOREM OR IPSUM
```

E.g.

[image: 0123 OR BOOM OR TAG OR LOREM OR IPSUM]

Alternatively if you wanted to search for ALL the terms simply remove the ORs, ie search for:

```
0123 BOOM TAG LOREM IPSUM
```