# Notepad++ find in files filter for files with no extension

Tags: notepad++, search, file-extension

I'm using Notepad++'s "Find in Files" functionality to find specific text in a large number of text files across a large number of directories and subdirectories. I understand how to specify file extensions in the filters section and that works fine for me. However, how can I only search in files that have no extension at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell NotePad++ uses the WinAPI [FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to filter the files, which I don't think has the functionality to find files without any extension. If you just want to search through files you might be better served with a dedicated file search program. There's a few recommendations here:

[Best way to *confidently* search files and contents in Windows without using an indexing service?](https://superuser.com/questions/26593/best-way-to-confidently-search-files-and-contents-in-windows-without-using-an)

Many programs support regular expressions and this regex should work for finding files without an extension: `^[^\.]+$`