# Windows 7 Search for Content Only

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I do not see any way to use Windows 7 search to search file content ONLY w/o it also including file names. For example, how do you search for files that contain "L:\" and only files that CONTAIN "L:\"? I do not want a list of files that have that in their name (filespec) but only a list of files that have that in their content.

Someone suggested L:\ System.FileName:NOT ~L:\ but that excludes all files with L:\ in their name (filespec) including the ones that contain "L:\".

Comment: Another similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/26593/best-way-to-confidently-search-files-and-contents-in-windows-without-using-an

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is as simple as:

> contents: L:\

You may need to make sure you've switched on the option to "Always search file names and contents"

Sorry, I don't have Windows 7 to test this, but it works fine on Windows 8.

Comment: This possibly requires Natural Language Search component, if you have custom (stripped) version of Windows, you may have it removed.

Answer (score 2):

Found filter option 'content:'. So use the filter option 'content:L:\'.

Comment: That's what I put in my answer, about 5 minutes before you :)   (content: or contents: works fine)